# "NS=: " in terminal profile when source .bashrc

Tags: bashrc

I don't know what have I done in my Ubuntu 12.04. But whenever I

```
igarcia@dulx0004:~$ source .bashrc
```

I get the following

```
[NS=:]igarcia@dulx0004:~$
```

What is going on?

Comment: It's probably of wrong typo in your bashrc file so please insert the result of `gedit ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I just found out, that the following line in the .bashrc causes it

export SU2_RUN="/usr/local/bin"

Comment: ok good to be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source .bashrc` is used to reload your bashrc file  without logging out and back in

The error raised is probably of wrong typo in your bashrc file so please check the syntax of your .bashrc  file